# Github Actions - Equivalent of Jenkins pipeline "fixed" status?

Tags: github, jenkins, automation, github-actions, slack

So in a Jenkins job, it has the usual post-run job status of "pass", "fail" and some others. There's also a fixed status; Which I think is if a job passes after it has failed before. Is there anything like this for Actions? I couldn't see anything in the docs, I'd like to have my job post to slack only if something has passed after a failure, but not every success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Jenkins [`post`](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#post) condition `fixed` applies if the current run is successful and the previous run failed or was unstable.

GitHub Actions [does not have a `post` equivalent](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/migrating-to-github-actions/manual-migrations/migrating-from-jenkins-to-github-actions#using-sections-to-organize-pipelines). A normal action can be used, so you have to define an job/step for this activity - for a functional equivalent.

You use [`needs`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/using-jobs-in-a-workflow#defining-prerequisite-jobs) to define the previous jobs it depends on. You use [`if`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/using-conditions-to-control-job-execution) to define the build state conditions.

From the [context availability](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#context-availability), which describes what data is available in the if condition, you can see that `success` is available.

However, for the last build status, looking at both `jobs.<job_id>.if` and `jobs.<job_id>.steps.if`, no special function nor context with applicable property exists. So the previous workflow result status has to be queried for via request.

You can do this with your own defined jobs and steps, or make use of a Marketplace action like [Get status of last workflow](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/get-status-of-last-workflow).

Their example includes a step that matches your condition case too:

```
        if: ${{ success() && steps.last_status.outputs.last_status == 'failure' }}
```

*in context:*

```
      - name: Build fixed slack message
        uses: rtCamp/action-slack-notify@v2.1.3
        if: ${{ success() && steps.last_status.outputs.last_status == 'failure' }}
        env: 
          SLACK_WEBHOOK: ${{ secrets.SLACK_WEBHOOK }}
          SLACK_MESSAGE: 'Style check fixed now!'
```